# Is there a way to create a transition between indexed stacks in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there an animation widget or a way to make transitions between indexed stacks. I am having the stack cover the entire page. Or is there an easier way to transition from one page to another if I made several pages. 
Thanks new to flutter.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I have used `AnimatedSwitcher` but the animations did not work. So I found that to animate we need to use a `Key` for each child.

In my case

```
 List<ValueKey<int>> _keys = [ValueKey<int>(0),ValueKey<int>(1),ValueKey<int>(2)];

 int _currentIndex = 0;
```

Now use Key in `AnimatedSwitcher` as below:

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  transitionBuilder: AnimatedSwitcher.defaultTransitionBuilder,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  child: IndexedStack(
    index: _currentIndex,
    key: ValueKey<int>(_currentIndex),
    children: [
      Page1(key: _keys[0],),
      Page2(key:_keys[1]),
      Page3(key:_keys[2])
    ],
  ),
);
```

change current index:

```
setState(() {
  _currentIndex = indexOfTabOrBottomNavItem;
});
```

NOTE: Using this way, you are not able to keep state of each widget.

**UPDATE :**
I am using animations package in my project.
You can use `PageTransitionSwitcher` from animations package. https://pub.dev/packages/animations

```
PageTransitionSwitcher(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
  transitionBuilder: (widget, anim1, anim2) {
    return FadeScaleTransition(
      animation: anim1,
      child: widget,
    );
  },
  child: IndexedStack(
    index: _currentIndex,
    key: ValueKey<int>(_currentIndex),
    children: [
      Page1(),
      Page2(),
      Page3()
    ],
  ),  
);
```

Comment: Hi, how can I use key property to keep my tab state? Without PageTransitionSwitcher and IndexedStack, my state is persistent. If I use PageTransitionSwitcher my state is not persistent. Can you post the code where you define and set keys? Thanks.

Comment: please help me here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65050756/flutter-cant-keep-the-state-of-tabs-using-pagetransitionswitcher

Comment: You can try out this custom widget: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56662#issuecomment-720678467

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is [`AnimatedSwitcher`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html).

e.g.

```dart
AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  child: _indexedArray[_index],
);
```

By default `AnimatedSwitcher` runs a fade-in transition. You can explore [`transitionBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher/transitionBuilder.html) property to run custom animation.

You might also want to take a look at [`AnimatedCrossFade`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html) if you need to switch only between 2 widgets.

Let me know if this helped.