# Flutter can't keep the state of tabs using PageTransitionSwitcher

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am struggling with [animations](https://pub.dev/packages/animations) package and I want to use animation with BottomNavigationBar.
Without animation, I can save my state using IndexedStack.
If I wrap IndexedStack inside PageTransitionSwitcher it doesn't work. In particular:

- animations are not showing but state is kept
- if I use key property of my IndexedStack, animations are showing but state is not working.

How can i fix it? I don't know how to set up keys.
Thank you very much!!

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'loading_screen';

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  int _selectedPage = 0;
  List<Widget> pageList = List<Widget>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    pageList.add(PrimoTab());
    pageList.add(SecondoTab());
    pageList.add(TerzoTab());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bottom tab'),
      ),
      body: PageTransitionSwitcher(
        transitionBuilder: (child, primaryAnimation, secondaryAnimation) {
          return SharedAxisTransition(
            animation: primaryAnimation,
            secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
            child: child,
            transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
          );
        },
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedPage,
          children: pageList,
          //key: ValueKey<int>(_selectedPage), NOT WORKING
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
            label: 'First Page',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
            label: 'Second Page',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            label: 'Third Page',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedPage,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.lightGreen,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPage = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Each tab is just a column with two text widgets, a button, and a text counter (for testing the state of each tab):

```
class PrimoTab extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _PrimoTabState createState() => _PrimoTabState();
}

class _PrimoTabState extends State<PrimoTab> {
  int cont = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              'TAB 1 - TEXT 1',
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              'TAB 1 - TEXT 2',
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                cont++;
              });
            },
            child: Text("CLICK"),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              'Valore contatore $cont',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

UPDATE 1: Using just

```
pageList[_selectedPage],
```

instead of

```
IndexedStack(
...
)
```

but not working (animations ok but state is not kept)

UPDATE 2 WITH SOLUTION (main.dart):

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MainScreen(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'loading_screen';

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  int _selectedPage = 0;
  List<Widget> pageList = List<Widget>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    pageList.add(PrimoTab());
    pageList.add(SecondoTab());
    pageList.add(TerzoTab());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bottom tab'),
      ),
      body: AnimatedIndexedStack(
        index: _selectedPage,
        children: pageList,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
            label: 'First Page',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
            label: 'Second Page',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            label: 'Third Page',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedPage,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.lightGreen,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPage = index;
    });
  }
}

class AnimatedIndexedStack extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final List<Widget> children;

  const AnimatedIndexedStack({
    Key key,
    this.index,
    this.children,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedIndexedStackState createState() => _AnimatedIndexedStackState();
}

class _AnimatedIndexedStackState extends State<AnimatedIndexedStack>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  int _index;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
    );
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller,
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
    );

    _index = widget.index;
    _controller.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(AnimatedIndexedStack oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.index != _index) {
      _controller.reverse().then((_) {
        setState(() => _index = widget.index);
        _controller.forward();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animation,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Opacity(
          opacity: _controller.value,
          child: Transform.scale(
            scale: 1.015 - (_controller.value * 0.015),
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: IndexedStack(
        index: _index,
        children: widget.children,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to fix your situation. None of them is perfectly simple and there already lots of discussion [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56662) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48217), trying to merge `IndexedStack` with `PageTransitionSwitcher`. No solution so far I saw.

I collect following possible ways to achieve this:

1. Store state somewhere else and pass into child. I haven't seen any method can stop `PageTransitionSwitcher` from rebuilding child widget. **If you don't mine the child widget rebuild**, it may be the most straight forward method to do with this.
2. Use Custom `IndexedStack` with animation. like [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48217#issuecomment-582535377) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535289/666221). It works well with the feature in IndexStack that children won't rebuild, but the animation is not as good as `PageTransitionSwitcher` and it can only show 1 widget in one time.

Comment: not working :(
animation is ok but state is not kept!

Comment: Oops, I must miss part of your question at first glance. I update the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

This was the closest solution I found. You get little animation while preserving the state of the page

```
class AnimatedIndexedStack extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final List<Widget> children;

  const AnimatedIndexedStack({
    Key key,
    this.index,
    this.children,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedIndexedStackState createState() => _AnimatedIndexedStackState();
}

class _AnimatedIndexedStackState extends State<AnimatedIndexedStack>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  int _index;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
    );
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller,
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
    );

    _index = widget.index;
    _controller.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(AnimatedIndexedStack oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.index != _index) {
      _controller.reverse().then((_) {
        setState(() => _index = widget.index);
        _controller.forward();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animation,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Opacity(
          opacity: _controller.value,
          child: Transform.scale(
            scale: 1.015 - (_controller.value * 0.015),
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: IndexedStack(
        index: _index,
        children: widget.children,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```