# how to use TabBar view inside scrollable widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I have this design, The first section in the red box is fixed height size, and The second section is the dynamic height (ListviewBuilder) which changed the content based on the tabBar.
My question is How can I use the TabBar view inside the scrollable widget (custom scroll view/listview etc..)

the solution That I currently found is to use a customScrollView and use SliverFillRemaining like that

```
   SliverFillRemaining(
        child: TabBarView(
          children: [],
        ),
      ),
```

but that adds extra white space at the bottom of the list and I can't remove it by
making hasScrollBody property false

Comment: Are you sure that `SliverFillRemaining` is not adding the extra space?

Comment: @AnteBule it is adding extra space and usually if you want to remove the extra space you need to make hasScrollBody = > false, but I found you can't make this property false if the child of SliverFillRemaining is TabBarView

Comment: You can achieve that with `IndexedStack` but then you lose swipe behavior (but this answer should help you with that https://stackoverflow.com/a/64131502/17104517)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably achieve what you want with this kind of template :

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .33,
          child: Container(/* Content of the first section */),
          ),
      Expanded(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: TabBar(
                    tabs: [Text("Guest"), Text("Service")],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    // Your ListView Builder here
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Seeing the bit of code you posted, it is probably close to what you already have but after test it doesn't adds extra white space at the bottom.

If it continue to display the same behavior, adding a little more context could help us provide a more accurate answer.